# Add leading zeros to character column in a Spark data frame using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

How can I add leading zeroes to `data$var1` in the following MWE?

```
library(sparklyr)
data <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("ab", "abc", "abcd"),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 3)
)
data <- sdf_copy_to(sc, data, "data", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The data frame I would like to achieve (preferably by using `dplyr::mutate`) is:

```
# Source: spark<data> [?? x 2]
  var1   var2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 00ab      1
2 0abc      2
3 abcd      3
```

I have already tried `SparkR::lpad`, `stringr::str_pad`, `sprintf` etc. but with no luck.

Comment: is this what you are looking for:
`data %>%
  mutate(var1 = str_pad(var1, 4, "left", "0")`

Comment: An alternative to the code provided by Cettt which works for any length of strings in var1 would be `data %>% mutate(var1 = str_pad(var1, max(nchar(data$var1)), "left", "0"))`

Comment: Your solutions does not work on a Spark data frame. Error messages tells me that `str_pad() is not available in this SQL variant`.

Answer (score 0):

For whom it might be relevant, the solution I found was to use SQL directly instead of trying to rely on a `sparklyr` translation from `R` to `SQL` (which is what's happening under the hood of `sparklyr`, as far as I understand).

```
sparklyr::sdf_sql(sc, "SELECT LPAD(var1, 4, '0') AS var3 FROM data")
```